# Newtonsoft - how to throw exception if property is missing?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a simple function:

```
public JsonResult FetchData(object obj)
{
  var jsonData = new { dateTime = DateTime.Today };
  jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(obj.ToString(), jsonData);
}
```

CASE A:
If I use json data 
`{"dateTime":"2018-09-24"}`
I can get right date: 2018-09-24

CASE B:
If I use json data, variable name has a blank space
`{"dateTime ":"2018-09-24"}`
I get date: 0001-01-01, without any exception.
"dateTime " is not a valid variable name for me

The behaviour I want is for CASE B to throw an exception or notice this case is invalid. How do I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Avoid CASE B by not having identifiers with spaces in them!

Comment: I add an additional  check "jsonData.dateTime<new DateTime(2010,1,1)" to avoid the invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper data structure to deserialise and you can control the property names with the `JsonProperty` attribute:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("dateTime ")] //Note the space in here
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And now deserialise like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
```

Comment: I want CASE B throw an exception

Comment: That's not what your question says.